# How to calculate integral of function bounded by an area

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Say I have a function f(x,y) and I need to find the integral of the function such that

$$x+y<\alpha$$
$$x<0, y<0$$

How do I define the limits? The bounds define a triangle along the x and y-axis which can be defined by the line $$\alpha- x/\alpha$$I thought that I can integrate from

$$\int^{\alpha}_{0} \int_{0}^{\alpha-x/\alpha} f(x,y) dy dx$$ but this doesn't work.

If we run this for $f(x,y)=1$ and $\alpha=2$, we get

$$\int^{2}_{0} \int_{0}^{2-x/2} 1 dy dx = 3$$.

Since this is a triangle, we should get the integral to be 2.

I'm sure that this has been answered elsewhere but I can't find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the only restriction is $x+y < \alpha$, the integral is to be computed on the region
$$
D=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2: -\infty < x < +\infty, -\infty < y < \alpha - x\}. 
$$

This corresponds to
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\alpha-x} f(x,y) dy \, dx.
$$

You seem to be  assuming that $x,y>0$, but you don't state it as a condition.

Comment: The OP seems to have changed, i'll edit accordingly.

Comment: Oh my god I'm dumb. I set the limits wrong. Should I delete this question?

Comment: @Durkee If you sorted it out, it is better to delete.